# javascript import has as default path the hard disk instead of node_modules

Tags: javascript, import, node-modules

My problem is that when I do an import the default path is the computer's hard drive. Instead of being node_modules.

In the import of the js file is set "type=module", so that's not the problem.

I have a badly configured Node or NPM, but I really don't know what to do.

In the images you can clearly see when I put "/" and the options appear that I am in the general hard drive of the computer.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd4l5.png)

[image example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PKiV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go one step back in the path like this: `import '../../js.js'`